# PHP readdir dots keep being shown

Tags: php, html, css, lightbox

I have written a simple image gallery scrip witch checks a folder and displays all the images in the folder i have code to remove the . and .. but its not working and I cant see why any help would be great as im new to the dir functions in PHP. I have lightbox tags surrounding the link hence the extra echo's The code is below:

```
<?
// USER OPTIONS DEDFINED HERE

$dir = "img/";      //folder with images
$height ="196px";   //image height on page its displayed in full in lightbox
$width ="320px";    //image width on page its displayed in full in lightbox
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Gallery</title> 
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</head>

<?

//open directory
if ($opendir = opendir($dir));

{

//read dir
while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($opendir)))
{   
    if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
        echo "<div class='imgwraper'>";
        echo"<a href='$dir$file' rel='lightbox[gallery]' title='$filename'>";
        echo "<img src='$dir$file' alt='' width='$width' height='$height'/>";
        echo"</a>";
        echo "<div class='name_box'>";
        echo current(explode('.', $file));
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

}
closedir($opendir); 
}

?>
```

Thanks in Advance

Lewis

Comment: The IF statement only applies to your first echo!

Comment: In addition to the braces to creat an actual if block as mentioned elsewhere, remove the semicolon in `if ($opendir = opendir($dir));`

Comment: Also: `&&$file` means `the address of the address of the variable $file`. You should change that to ` && $file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no braces after `if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")`, the `if` statement is only applicable for the first line of `echo "<div class='imgwraper'>";`.

Wrap everything in braces like so:

```
while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($opendir)))
{   
    if ($file!="."&&$file!="..") {
        echo "<div class='imgwraper'>";
        echo"<a href='$dir$file' rel='lightbox[gallery]' title='$filename'>";
        echo "<img src='$dir$file' alt='' width='$width' height='$height'/>";
        echo"</a>";
        echo "<div class='name_box'>";
        echo current(explode('.', $file));
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

By the way, you could consider using `glob` to simplify your code a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for that ill look into glob never heard of it

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to wrap your if statement in curly brackets.

```php
while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($opendir)))
{   
if ($file!="."&&$file!=".."){
    echo "<div class='imgwraper'>";
    echo"<a href='$dir$file' rel='lightbox[gallery]' title='$filename'>";
    echo "<img src='$dir$file' alt='' width='$width' height='$height'/>";
    echo"</a>";
    echo "<div class='name_box'>";
    echo current(explode('.', $file));
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
}
```

Shai.